# Can I have a $ aligned to the left and 0 to the right?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

I am trying to format an Excel cell as per the example below. Is this possible?

```
$                0.00
$               24.20
$                0.00
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  You should take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Comment: Can you use two cells for each of these rows?  One = a $

Comment: Use custom format like `$ #,##0.00` and use justify alignment in same dialog to adjust both currency symbol & decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Accounting` format.

[image: Accounting format]

Alternatively, you can reach this format by using `Format Cells` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>), and customize to your liking (changing the currency, removing decimals, etc.)

Comment: ["Like the Currency format, the Accounting format is used for monetary values. But, this format aligns the currency symbols and decimal points of numbers in a column"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-numbers-as-currency-0a03bb38-1a07-458d-9e30-2b54366bc7a4)

Answer (score 0):

If format required is of the form "$ 1258.47" then :

Heading in First Row : Column 1 : "Amount" Col. 2 : "Formatted Amount"

Enter all values in A2, A3, A4 etc.

We use Concatenate Formula to get the result. 
In formula we can also use "&" to Concatenate.

So in Cell B2 Enter the formula : "$ "&A2
Copy the formula in B2, down the column to get desire format.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

To right align the format to see the unit digit under unit digit etc..

Enter Further Headings in First Row as :

C1="Lenth of Amount" : D1="Spaces Required" : E1="Pedding String"

F1="String Size" ; So suppose we need size of 18 then enter 17 in Cell F2
Because One for "$" is subtracted. THis will remain Constant and can be changed at any time by entering different value in Cell F2.

Now Enter Formulas as shown below :

In C2 Enter Formula : =LEN(A2)
In D2 Enter Formula : =$F$2 - C2     ( Absolute reference of the Cell )
In E2 Enter Formula : =REPT(" ",D2)  ( To repeat the spaces required )

Finally, Now in B2 enter the Formula : ="$"&E2&A2

Now copy the Formula of B2 down the column B to get the desired result.

I hope you are satisfied.

If not, or for any query please revert back.

Thanks.